# Node with NVM. Debian 9

Tags: node.js

I am installing node with nvm on my computer with Debian 9.

I need a specific version and be able to change it.

I follow all the steps according to the documentation:

```
nvm install v8.15.1
v8.15.1 is already installed.
Now using node v8.15.1 (npm v6.4.1)
```

But when I run node -v, it says it does not exist

```
node 
bash: nodejs: the order was not found
```

I have looked at several manuals and in all they are the same steps, I do not know why it does not work for me.

Comment: can u please run the command `nvm ls`  and show me what do u see?
try to run the command `nvm use <node version>` then check if node command is known

Comment: v8.15.1
       v11.13.0
         system
default -> 8.15.1 (-> v8.15.1)
node -> stable (-> v11.13.0) (default)
stable -> 11.13 (-> v11.13.0) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/dubnium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.15.1
lts/dubnium -> v10.15.3 (-> N/A)

Comment: I dont see anything weird or wrong in this output, assuming that u installed everything properly just try to run the command `nvm use <version>` and let me know if it works

Comment: It was that, I thought if I had done it. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome